# OpenGL ES/ iPhone Development Questions- First Game

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es

I'm currently working on my first iPhone game with openGLES- it is amazing! Loving every minute of it. However I have a couple questions:

1. I would like to make a particle system- what is the fastest way to do this? I would imagine that I could just make a mutable array of particle objects, however each particle would then have to be derived from NSObject, correct? This seems like it comes with quite a bit of overhead.. Is there a better way? In the past, with c++ I've used a vector of extremely simple particle objects, and swapped the dead particles to the end, and reuse those when I need a new particle- I'll likely do the same here. Just worried (perhaps unjustly) about efficiency.
2. How do I change the coordinate system of OpenGL to allow me to use 0-screensize as units instead of the default -1 to 1? (for instance, a simple vertex list using the points {-1,0,0,  1,0,0, 0,1,0} would make a triangle in which the hypotenuse stretched along the entirety of the center horizontal axis)
3. It looks as though I can't use shaders at all with 1.1, but 2.0 utilizes them for *everything* is there any reason for me to stick with 1.1?
4. Is there good reason to create my GUI completely in OpenGL? Or would I be well served to use the standard system? (such as creating a xib file with GUI elements)
5. Since I'm just beginning are there any common pitfalls that typically accompany OpenGL ES? I don't really intend this to be open-ended, I'm attempting to root out anything concrete that trips up a lot of new users of the specification.

Comment: Have you considered using a framework like Cocos2D?

Comment: Certainly- I have nothing against frameworks. I'm usually quite thick headed and like to roll my own... but I just don't know the spec well enough at the moment so something like cocos2d would probably be a good idea.

Comment: Should I break this question into multiples do ya think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I use regular C structs for mine, NSObjects are hogs in this context, on a 3G I can get 2000 particles no problem with C structs, less than 200 with objects.
2. Something like this will get you a 480x320 coordinate system:

   ```
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   CGRect rect = self.view.bounds;
   if (highRes && (retina == 1)) {
       glOrthof(0.0, rect.size.width/2, 0.0 ,  rect.size.height/2, -1, 1000.0);
   } else {
       glOrthof(0.0, rect.size.width, 0.0 ,  rect.size.height, -1, 1000.0);    
   }
   ```
3. Only to support older devices < 3GS.
4. Depends on the looks and work you want. If you need text input remember you have to do it from scratch in openGL, also font rendering, etc. Sometimes you can mix both (say open a drawer with you text boxes and such), but when mixing whats happening on opengl has to be very simple.
5. Lots of pitfalls, better get a good tutorial so you have the basics covered, something that goes from setting up your view to getting an model textured, after that you can refer back to it if something goes awry.

Good luck, make it a fun game :-)

Comment: Haha, thanks for the reply- I've gotten everything figured out, except what I wanted to do with particles, I appreciate it! (Oh it's already quite addicting, I'm spending more time playing the stupid game than making it!)